# how to aggregate mins data from HH:MM:SS string time value in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, aggregate

I have documents in mongodb collection in below format, and i want to aggregate into specific time frame lets say 5 mins, 10 mins, 15 mins etc...Collection details are as below,

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("603a7aec21a87324e49f7ce1"),
"Time" : "10:15:00",
"Rate" : "3250"
},
{
"_id" : ObjectId("603a7aec21a87324e49f7ce1"),
"Time" : "10:17:22",
"Rate" : "3250"
}
```

your suggestion are highly appreciated....

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow [take a tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), and see [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask), after reading this links, please update your question with more details, 1) your sample collection details is not valid please update valid json format, 2) what you have tried so far? 3) where you failed in your try?

Comment: Please provide some **valid** input sample data. This is not any collection data.

Comment: {
    "_id" : ObjectId("603a7aec21a87324e49f7ce1"),
    "Time" : "10:10:15",
    "Rate" : "2000.75",
}{
    "_id" : ObjectId("603a7aec21a87324e49f7ce1"),
    "Time" : "10:11:30",
    "Rate" : "2000.75",
}{
    "_id" : ObjectId("603a7aec21a87324e49f7ce1"),
    "Time" : "10:11:23",
    "Rate" : "2000.75",
}{
    "_id" : ObjectId("603a7aec21a87324e49f7ce1"),
    "Time" : "10:13:00",
    "Rate" : "2000.75",
}{
    "_id" : ObjectId("603a7aec21a87324e49f7ce1"),
    "Time" : "10:13:12",
    "Rate" : "2000.75",
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should store date/time values **never** as string, it's a design flaw. Use always proper `Date` object. Same applies for numeric values.

Have a look at this solution

```
var span = 1000 * 60 * 5 // => 5 Minutes
db.collection.aggregate([
   // Convert time strings to 'Date' values
   {
      $set: {
         date: { $regexFindAll: { input: "$Time", regex: /\d+/ } }
      }
   },
   {
      $set: {
         date: {
            $dateFromParts: {
               year: 1970, month: 1, day: 1,
               hour: { $toInt: { $arrayElemAt: ["$date.match", 0] } },
               minute: { $toInt: { $arrayElemAt: ["$date.match", 1] } },
               second: { $toInt: { $arrayElemAt: ["$date.match", 2] } }
            }
         }
      }
   },
   // Create the interval
   {
      $set: {
         interval: {
            $dateFromParts: {
               year: 1970, month: 1, day: 1,
               millisecond: { $multiply: [span, { $trunc: { $divide: [{ $toLong: "$date" }, span] } }] },
            }
         }
      }
   },
   // Group by interval
   { $group: { _id: "$interval", Rate: { $sum: "$Rate" } } }
])
```

[Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/ax3-F0Uuoq8)

Comment: Thanks @wernfried domscheit, This works well for me. I will also try to change the datatype of Time field in my collection.